# My controller reponse with HTTP ERROR 404

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

My products controller reponse with HTTP ERROR 404 when I try to call https://localhost:44328/Products

**My ProductsController**

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private readonly CmsShoppingCartContext _context;

    public ProductsController(CmsShoppingCartContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    // GET /products
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int p = 1)
    {

        //tag helper
        int pageSize = 6;
        //The skip is to skip 0, 1-1*6 is zero. So it starts with one
        var products = _context.Products.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
            .Skip((p - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize);

        ViewBag.PageNumber = p;
        ViewBag.PageRange = pageSize;
        ViewBag.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)_context.Products.Count() / pageSize);

        return View(await products.ToListAsync());


    }
```

**My Index.html (in folder Views/Products)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide code, don't images

Comment: And please show the Route.cs file

Comment: I'm new in MVC.. you mean the startup.cs?

Comment: no, found the app_Start folder

Comment: I'm not really sure. I dont have this folder in my project. 
The problem is, that https://localhost:44328/Products doesn't work. But https://localhost:44328/Products/Shirt works fine.

Comment: because maybe your controller doesn't allow null as optional id. Idk, I need more debug details.

Comment: For somehow I cant edit the question and add code. So I'm sorry to add pictures :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using mapendpoints, try to add a route attribute to the endpoint

```
[Route("~/Products/{p?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int p = 1)
```

another way is to map a controller but I don't recommend to go this way , since it is very confusing and not always working as expected

```
[Route("~/Products")]
public class ProductsController : Controller

....

[HttpGet("{p?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int p = 1)
```

Comment: Now I'm getting GET https://localhost:44328/products 500

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).

Comment: @djxenon Error 500 has nothing to do with routing. It is a common error when something is wrong at the server. As far as I can juge from error message it is Authentication user error.  Do you use token or something like it?

Comment: Doesn't make sense.. because https://localhost:44328/products/shirt works fine.. but not https://localhost:44328/products/

And that is without the routing you wrote that i should add

Comment: @djxenon google.ca is working too. Why  are  you comparing different actions?